# Составить программу в C++

Tags: c++

Даны действительные числа х, у, z. Получить:
a) max(x,y,z);
b)min(x,y,z), max(x,y,z).

Comment: И что, вы не знаете, как сравнивают числа?...

Answer (score 2):

```
Супер легкая задача, разберу пример  a) max(x,y,z) :
int bigest = y; 
if(x > y){
   bigest = x;
}
if(bigest < z){
   bigest = z;
}
```

Comment: разве `bigest` не нужно приравнять к `y`, в вашем случае ? если `y` будет больше всех, то в `bigest` он не запишется

Comment: да, правильная заметка